# Vue Component Templates

Tags: vue.js

I would like to add a dynamic class attribute inside the template, provided by a simple custom component:

```
Vue.component('cards',{
                props:['element'],
                template:'<div v-bind:class="\'item\'-element"> 
                {{element}}</div>' 
      })
    
      <cards
            v-for="(card,index) in cards"
            v-bind:element="index"
      >
      </cards>
      const app = new Vue({
                el: '#app',
                data: {
                    cards: [1,3,4,2],
                    clicked: false
                }
      })
```

But the rendered template is:

```
<div class="">1</div>
<div class="">2</div>
<div class="">4</div>
<div class="">2</div>
```

I expected something like:

```
 <div class="1">1</div>
```

Moreover, if I would make a more dynamic class name, like:

```
<div class="class-1">1</div>
<div class="class-2">1</div>
```

How to do it inside the component template?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's because you use `element` prop in the wrong way because what you write is `-element`. it's easier to understand and cleaner if you use template literals.

change your binded class to this:

```js
<div v-bind:class="`item-${element}`">
```

or

```js
<div :class="`item-${element}`">
```

Comment: thank you! So I learnt the vue "extract" the string value from the bind directive and evaluate it.

Answer (score 0):

There is issue in v-bind:class attribute,
you are subtracting string 'item' with iterator element (a number)

I recommend to use + operator to concat and put minus sign inside quotes like:

v-bind:class="'item-' + element"

or replace item with class like:

v-bind:class="'class-' + element"